# customize asp.net 4.0 menu control

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

Is there a way to apply your own CSS tags to `<li>` tags when using ASP .NET 4.0 menu control? For example, say I have an external style sheet that has tags "class1", "class2", "class3", and etc. I want to apply "class1" to the first menu item. Then if menu item is selected, I want to apply "class2" and if it's not selected, "class3". I played with various 'Static' styles, but just can't get it work. I finally gave up and created my own menu control that extends ASP .NET menu control and provides my own custom rendering. This works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get it work with built-in menu control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its much hard to make the asp.net menu control work. Yes they accept the css but then there will be the browser compatibility issue. Its good to use the own customized menu, even you can develop the own Multilevel customized menu by taking some JQUERY from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/

Comment: My menu control is really simple and I wanted to use existing control. So for now I ended up with extending standard asp.net menu control and completely replacing rendering part. Dynamicdrive menu is something to look at though.